# On proving that a certain subset is dense in a metric space of probability measures equipped with Prohorov metric

Tags: general-topology, probability-theory

If $S $ is a separable space and $\{s_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\} $ is a countable dense subset of $S, $ I would like to define the following probability measure on $S: $
$$ P_M = \sum_{i=1}^M a_i\delta_{s_i} $$
with $M $ finite,  $\delta_{s_i} $ the probability measure that assigns unit mass at $s_i \in S $ for each $i = 1, 2, \ldots, $ and $a_i \in \mathbb{Q} $ such that
$\sum_{i=1}^M a_i = 1. $ 
Is the set of probability measures $\{P_n: n \in \mathbb{N}\} $ thus defined dense in $({\cal P}(S), \rho) $ where ${\cal P}(S) $ represents the collection of Borel probability measures on $(S, {\cal B}(S)) $ and $\rho $ is the Prohorov distance?
Prohorov distance is defined as 
$$ \rho(P, Q) = \inf\{\epsilon > 0: P(F) \le Q(F^\epsilon) + \epsilon\} $$
for all closed sets $F $ of $S $ and $F^\epsilon =\{x\in S: \inf_{y\in F} d(x, y) < \epsilon\},  $ i.e., $F^\epsilon = \{x\in S: d(x, F) < \epsilon\}. $

I think it is and it should not even be too difficult to prove it, but sometimes I think that my appetite is bigger than my stomach. Any help in proving that the set of probability measures above is dense in  $({\cal P}(S), \rho) $
would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Maurice

Comment: Not sure how to go with that, but you can use that the Prokhorov metric is topologically equivalent to the Kantorovich metric. So since you need to work with Lipschitz continuous functions, things may become easier.

Comment: Are you suggesting some kind of embedding?